# Bootstrap in VueJS not working properly (app.scss is not loading and also b-alert dismissable is a square button with an x in the middle!)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

This is the first time i am using bootstrap in my vuejs project and there are two things which are not clear to me.

I followed the guide here [bootstrap in vuejs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-module-bundlers) and step by step i added until i had to create app.scss and i decided to put it in assets folder and once i import that file inside my main.js i get a long error from vuejs.

Second problem:
I decided to give up on app.scss global styling (if that is the correct terminology) and just try out bootstrap, as a bare bone example i found this example [bootstrap playground](https://bootstrap-vue.org/play) and i copied and pasted it into my vue project.

Now i see some styling with the buttons but the result is not the same as the output of the aforementioned website.

My dismiss button is gray with borders and X inside it and it is on the left side of the text. The play ground example X button is located at the right hand side of the text, it is styled properly and has no borders and the color is green/blueish.

This is probably very basic stuff but if someone can tell me what i am doing wrong i would be grateful since i followed the documentation and honestly searched for 3 hours and no solutions.

Comment: Try double checking what version of Bootstrap you've installed. It should be Bootstrap 4, and not Bootstrap 5.

Comment: To rule it out:
b-alert indicates, that you use bootstrap-vue, which is not supported in vue3, but works fine in vue2.

Which Version of Vue do you use?

Comment: I am using version 2.6.4

Comment: So far i tried @Hiws solution and reverted back to Bootstrap 4, everything works from the documentation links of vue-bootstrap. I don't I am going to close this question but it would be neat to find out what i did wrong for future projects.

Comment: Well, if you've "reverted back to Bootstrap 4", it sounds like you had Bootstrap 5 installed, which BootstrapVue doesn't support as it's currently built for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

As Hiws indicates in the comments above, this is probably due to the wrong Bootstrap version.  I had this exact thing happen when I had Bootstrap 5 installed, and when I changed it to use Bootstrap 4 instead, the dismissable dialog functioned as I expected it to.